# k-medoids algorithm with incomplete distance matrix

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, k-means

I want to apply k-medoids algorithm using an incomplete distance matrix as input. How can I handle the lack of information of this matrix? Just ignoring the missing distances? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could of course try to impute missing values.

But unless you are missing a lot of data, you may get reasonable results with just skipping missing values, and only adjusting PAM with respect to the amount of data you are missing when trying to identify the most central element.

Have you tried anything yet? Go for it!

Comment: I actually just realized I was missing points. I implemented k-medoids with the points I had but when I tried to compute the silhouette, I found out I had missing points